# How to combine MemberExpression instances in C# for a LambdaExpression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Given a class like this:

```
public class AnEntity
{
    public int prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to generate a lambda expression that selects one property like this:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AnEntity), "x");
MemberExpression selectClause = Expression
    .MakeMemberExpression(
        pe, 
        typeof(AnEntity).GetProperty(prop2)); // selecting prop2

var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<AnEntity, object>>(selectClause, pe);
```

I can then use the lambda expression like this:

```
IQueryable<AnEntity> myEntities = dbContext.MyEntities.AsQueryable();
var results = myEntities.Select(selectLambda);
```

How can I add a second select clause to the selectLambda? For example, how would I select both prop2 and prop3?

Comment: It depends on how you would want to select both at the same time. Into an anonymous object? A `Tuple`? An array? Something else?

Comment: I suppose I just assumed that is what it would have to be. `myEntities.Select(x => new { x.prop2, x.prop3 });`

Comment: AFAIK projecting into an anonymous type when the names and types of its properties are only known at runtime would be a **major** pain (`Reflection.Emit`, creating and loading a dynamic assembly). If you want maximum flexibility and intend to solve a practical problem instead of venturing into the unknown, go with a `Tuple`.

Comment: In my case, the properties to be selected are only known at runtime. And yes... it has been a major pain so far :-)

Answer (score 2):

Below is a fleshed out example of what "usr" described in his solution using MemberInitExpression.

For my solution, I am going to provide you with a new class that you will want write the expression result into. In reality, this could be the POCO for the entity itself, but by specifying a different class, it is clearer which class is the class you are projecting into as compared to the class you are projecting from. As "usr" mentioned, you can also try to use Tuple or other constructs. My current favorite is to use the extra code I appended to the bottom to create a new type dynamically. This is a bit more flexible than Tuple, but it has some disadvantages in that it requires Reflection to access it for the most part.

Class to project into:

```
public class Holder
{
    public int Item1{ get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Code to create expression:

```
ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AnEntity));
NewExpression newHolder = Expression.New(typeof(Holder));    
Type anonType = typeof(Holder);                
MemberInfo item1Member = anonType.GetMember("Item1")[0];
MemberInfo item2Member = anonType.GetMember("Item2")[0];
MemberInfo item3Member = anonType.GetMember("Item3")[0];

// Create a MemberBinding object for each member 
// that you want to initialize.
 MemberBinding item1MemberBinding =
 Expression.Bind(
     item1Member,
     Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExp, "prop1"));
 MemberBinding item2MemberBinding =
 Expression.Bind(
     item2Member,
     Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExp, "prop2"));
 MemberBinding item3MemberBinding =
 Expression.Bind(
     item3Member,
     Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExp, "prop3"));

// Create a MemberInitExpression that represents initializing 
// two members of the 'Animal' class.
MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression =
    Expression.MemberInit(
        newHolder,
        item1MemberBinding,
        item2MemberBinding,
        item3MemberBinding);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<AnEntity, Holder>>(memberInitExpression, paramExp);
```

Finally, how you would call the expression:

```
IQueryable<AnEntity> myEntities = dbContext.MyEntities.AsQueryable();
var results = myEntities.Select(selectLambda);
```

Here is some additional code if you wanted to define a type dynamically for the return value:

```
    public static Type CreateNewType(string assemblyName, string typeName, params Type[] types)
    {
        // Let's start by creating a new assembly
        AssemblyName dynamicAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(assemblyName);
        AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName);

        // Now let's build a new type
        TypeBuilder dynamicAnonymousType = dynamicModule.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);

        // Let's add some fields to the type.
        int itemNo = 1;
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField("Item" + itemNo++, type, FieldAttributes.Public);
        }

        // Return the type to the caller
        return dynamicAnonymousType.CreateType();
    }
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this. I'll take a look at this asap. It's been a while since I first posted the question, and we ended up solving the issue a different way. But, this looks really cool.

Comment: what is anonType?

Answer (score 1):

The way to answer questions like these is to write the pattern you want to build in strongly typed C# (`select new { x.p1, x.p2 }`) and use the debugger to look at the expression tree. Then you build that tree yourself.

What you will find is a `MemberInitExpression` instantiating a class with the two properties `p1` and `p2` that are being initialized from `x`.

You have to supply such a class somehow. Either define it yourself (`class X { string p1, p2; }`) or use a `Tuple`-like construct. Or an `object[]`.

Understand that you can only have **one return value**. So it needs to encapsulate multiple values.

The easiest way is going to be using an `object[]`. Look at how the C# compiler does it.

Comment: The C# compiler probably creates a `MemberInitExpression` for that actually.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply a tuple or object[] in this case.

Comment: You could select like this: `IEnumerable<object[]> rows = myList.Select(x => new object[] { x.p1, x.p2 })`. Does that help? Any specific things I need to elaborate on?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to working with expressions and expression trees. How would I translate `new object[] { x.prop1, x. prop2 }` into an expression created at runtime?

Comment: @quakkels do it in C#, then look at the resulting tree in the debugger. Or decompile the executable using Reflector or any other decompiler of your choice. The C# compiler uses the `Expression.*` API just like a developer would. Looks like you need to create a `NewArrayExpression` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "second select return value".  You get to return one value, which might be an aggregate.

The C# language provides a lot of syntactic sugar in this area, in the form of LINQ and anonymous types.  To return an aggregate via a lambda built by expression trees, you'll have to create a type to hold all the different values (just like the C# compiler does behind the scenes when it sees an anonymous type) and then call its constructor passing the multiple values you want to return (this is actually somewhat easier than what C# does behind the scenes, which is call a bunch of property setters).  At runtime, there are no anonymous types.  They all get named, if not by the programmer then by the compiler.

In fact you can probably use a `Tuple<Type1, Type2, Type3>` instead of making a class especially for the purpose.  But then your member properties won't be named nicely.

Comment: would I be able to use tuple without knowing the types until runtime?

Comment: @quakkels: Yes, you can use `typeof (Tuple<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { RuntimeType1, RuntimeType2 })`