# Create MemberInitExpression programmatically from Class/object for EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Using [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) Update method I need a MemberInitExpression as Parameter.

```
await _db.Users
    .Where(u => u.Username == user.Username)
    .UpdateAsync(x => new User { Username = "manfred" });
```

However I want to set all Properties in a programmatic way from an given User object (not only the username like in the example).

I want to do this in a programmatic way to avoid missing newly added properties on the user object later in the development cycle.

EDIT: I tried something like this, however this is not working and I can't set values

```
Type t = User.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();

ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
NewExpression newHolder = Expression.New(typeof(User));
var memberBindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var methodInfo = prop.GetMethod;
    //var binding = Expression.Bind(methodInfo, paramExp);
    var binding = Expression.Bind(methodInfo, Expression.Parameter(methodInfo.GetType(), methodInfo.Name));
    memberBindings.Add(binding);
}
MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression =
    Expression.MemberInit(
        newHolder, memberBindings);
```

Comment: Which difficulties do you have with `MemberInitExpression`? What you have tried?

Comment: The Problem I have is that I have to write them by hand and therefore there are not feature proof and error prone.

Comment: No other solutions here. You have unknown count of properties - you have to use reflection or `conext.Model.FindEntityType(type).GetProperties()` info.

Comment: I was thinking about Reflection however I don't know how to create a MemberInitExpression from code (and did not find an example where values were mapped - in this example I think they generate it, however they don't map values https://stackoverflow.com/a/23947625/2298744 )

Comment: Now I see your mistakes. Another question, how do you plan to filter out PrimaryKey columns or columns generated by server?

Comment: This is easy and can be done using (exisiting) Attributes. The most important thing for me is to reduce future errors when just adding a property on the Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have variable

```cs
User user;
```

holding `User` instance coming from somewhere. And you want expression

```cs
(User x) => new User { Prop1 = user.Prop1, Prop2 = user.Prop2, ... }
```

which is lambda expression with parameter `x` and body being indeed `MemberInitExpression`. `new User` corresponds to `NewExpression`, and assignments inside are `MemberBinding`s. The first argument of the `Expression.Bind` is simply the `PropertyInfo`, and the second is `Expression.Property` applied to *constant* expression holding the `user` variable value (`User` instance). It has to be constant because it is not coming from parameter.

Taking your code

```cs
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = t.GetProperties();
```

It can be obtained from EF Core metadata, and also has to be tuned to at least exclude the PK properties, but assuming it holds the list of `PropertyInfo` to be applied, the desired bindings can be build as follows:

```cs
var memberBindings = props
    .Select(prop => Expression.Bind(
        prop, Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(user), prop)))
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, the `user` variable properties could be evaluated and passed as constants (not sure if that affects the `Update` method):

```cs
var memberBindings = props
    .Select(prop => Expression.Bind(
        prop, Expression.Constant(prop.GetValue(user), prop.PropertyType)))
    .ToList();
```

The rest of the code is the same as in the original post. `ToList` is not really needed and can be removed from the above code, since `Expression.MemberInit` accepts `IEnumerable<MemberBinding>`.

Comment: I think better to use `Expression.Contant(user)` and provide values for update via `Expression.MakeMemberAccess(userConst, prop)` It will create parametrised query end SQL server will be happy to reuse execution plan.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I agree, that's why it was the first option. And I know what EF Core translator will do. But not sure for that 3rd party `Update` method. That's why the 2 options :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav `Expression.MakeMemberAccess(userConst, prop)` is the same as `Expression.Property(userConst, prop)` when `prop` type is `PropertyInfo`. `MakeMemberAccess` is the equivalent of `PropertyOrField` when having `MemberInfo` instead of `string` name.

Comment: My fault ;) Yes third party extension which do not have LINQ translator may not work with parameters.

Comment: Thank your for the answer, I was able to implement it. I posted the code bellow for others to copy. If I got the comments correctly: using MakeMemberAccess or Property Expressions would be more performant? I also saw that there is an Increment Expression, is it possible to use it as well? (I was not able to figure out how to use the Increment Expression)

Comment: (1) The performance difference between `MakeMemberAccess` and `Property` is negligible, but the later is preferable when you have `PropertyInfo` object. The former is receiving `MemberInfo`, which is the common base class of `PropertyInfo` and `FieldInfo`, and inside is calling either `Property` or `Field` (2) `Expression.Increment` is a shortcut for `x + 1` where `x` is some integer type  expression, and usually is not used in query expression trees. Not sure if it's supported by the query processors at all, so you'd better not use it.

Comment: Thanks for your explinaton an well crafted answer :)
(2) so there is no way to easily increment a column in efcore (or with lib)?

Comment: @Fritz In EF Core (out of the box) - no. With 3rd party library you are using - I'm not sure, and can find some sort of documentation showing a syntax from that. If there is a syntax, we can always build the expression :)

Comment: I'm new to EFcore and SQL in general, so I'm open for all kind of libraries. In EFcore I really like the automatically generated Migrations. However because of the restrictions of an ORM I'm thinking of writing Stored Procedures, but I don't like that the need to be defined in the Migrations itself not somewhere in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answere of Ivan Stoev I created the following Code:

It handles FKs and ReadOnly Properties.
I had to additionally create a Lambda for the Update method to accept the MemberInitExpression.

```cs
Type t = User.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();

ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
NewExpression newHolder = Expression.New(typeof(User));

var memberBindings = props
    .Select(prop =>
    {
        if (!prop.CanWrite)
            return null;

        if (prop.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(KeyAttribute)))
            return null;
        
        if (prop.Name == "SomeObject")
            return null;

        return Expression.Bind(
            prop, Expression.Constant(prop.GetValue(User), prop.PropertyType));
    })
    .Where(m => m != null)
    .ToList();

MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression =
    Expression.MemberInit(
        newHolder, memberBindings);
Expression<Func<User, User>> lambda =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<User, User>>(memberInitExpression, paramExp);

var updates = await _db.Users
    .Where(c => c.Username == User.Username )
    .UpdateAsync(lambda);
```